# ¿Cómo agrupar y contar los registros ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo esta consulta:

```
 SELECT count(*), time_stamp, org_account, result, mt_msc_addr
    FROM sms_data_mtbill
   WHERE time_stamp >= TO_DATE ('28-11-2018 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
    and mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY time_stamp, org_account, result, mt_msc_addr
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
```

Pero al momento de traeme los datos no me muestra el resultado del `count` bien estoy utilizando ORACLE.

Éste es el resultado de la consulta que me arroja:

```
1   29/11/2018 12:19:19 p. m.   Gateway_G   0   5691600020
1   29/11/2018 12:19:19 p. m.   OtaDMC      0   5691600019
2   29/11/2018 12:19:19 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:19 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:19 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600020
1   29/11/2018 12:19:18 p. m.   Gateway_G   0   5691600020
1   29/11/2018 12:19:18 p. m.   OtaDMC      0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:18 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:18 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5691600023
1   29/11/2018 12:19:18 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600019
2   29/11/2018 12:19:18 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600020
1   29/11/2018 12:19:17 p. m.   OtaDMC      0   5691600019
2   29/11/2018 12:19:17 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5691600023
1   29/11/2018 12:19:17 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5692099064
1   29/11/2018 12:19:17 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5692099178
1   29/11/2018 12:19:17 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5692099587
1   29/11/2018 12:19:16 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5691600023
1   29/11/2018 12:19:16 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5692099064
1   29/11/2018 12:19:16 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5692099178
1   29/11/2018 12:19:16 p. m.   otarca1     1   5691600023
1   29/11/2018 12:19:16 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:15 p. m.   Gateway_G   0   5691600023
1   29/11/2018 12:19:15 p. m.   sdp         0   5691600020
1   29/11/2018 12:19:15 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:14 p. m.   Gateway_G   0   5691600020
1   29/11/2018 12:19:14 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5691600020
1   29/11/2018 12:19:14 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600023
1   29/11/2018 12:19:14 p. m.   smsgw       0   5692099064
1   29/11/2018 12:19:13 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5691600020
1   29/11/2018 12:19:13 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5692099062
1   29/11/2018 12:19:13 p. m.   otarca1     1   5691600020
2   29/11/2018 12:19:13 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:12 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:12 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5692099061
2   29/11/2018 12:19:12 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:12 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600020
2   29/11/2018 12:19:12 p. m.   smsgw       0   5692099587
1   29/11/2018 12:19:12 p. m.   smsgw       1   5691600020
1   29/11/2018 12:19:11 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5691600023
1   29/11/2018 12:19:11 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600019
1   29/11/2018 12:19:11 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600020
2   29/11/2018 12:19:11 p. m.   smsgw       0   5691600023
1   29/11/2018 12:19:10 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5692099064
1   29/11/2018 12:19:10 p. m.   VMSTRWI     0   5692099587
```

Comment: Los resultados a simple vista parecen bien agrupados por las columnas que indicas: `time_stamp, org_account, result, mt_msc_addr`  ¿Acaso hay alguno que se repite? ¿O, cuál es el problema, qué resultados esperas?

Comment: En preguntas de este tipo siempre es buena idea incluir un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que se desea producir. De otra forma, quien se interese en ayudarte tiene una tarea difícil para intentar averiguar cual es el problema. Te invito a leer [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: Sin ejemplo de datos usados, es bien difícil analizar la salida. Posiblemente está haciendo lo que le dices que haga y el problema es de diseño en la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución:

```
select count(*) from (SELECT count(*), time_stamp, org_account, result, mt_msc_addr
    FROM sms_data_mtbill
   WHERE time_stamp >= TO_DATE ('28-11-2018 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
    and mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY time_stamp, org_account, result, mt_msc_addr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SI está agrupando, pero seguramente el campo time_stamp tiene una precisión mayor a la mostrada en los datos del ejemplo.

Lo puedes comprobar fácilmente convirtiendo el valor a una cadena que contenga fracciones de segundo, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT top 10 time_stamp, to_char(time_stamp 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ssxff4') ts
  FROM sms_data_mtbill
 WHERE time_stamp >= TO_DATE ('28-11-2018 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
   and mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
```

Dado que, seguramente quieres agrupar por ese *time_stamp*, pero con una precisión menor, tienes estas opciones:

- Si quieres agrupar con precisión hasta el segundo, la opción con mejor desempeño te la daría hacer un [*cast*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CAST.html) sobre el campo eliminando las fracciones de segundo. Esto puedes lograrlo convirtiéndolo al tipo [`timestamp(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html), por ejemplo:

  ```
    SELECT   count(*)
           , cast(time_stamp as timestamp(0)) ts
           , org_account
           , result
           , mt_msc_addr
      FROM sms_data_mtbill
     WHERE time_stamp >= TO_DATE ('28-11-2018 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
       and mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY cast(time_stamp as timestamp(0)), org_account, result, mt_msc_addr
     ORDER BY cast(time_stamp as timestamp(0)) DESC
  ```
- Si quieres agrupar con otra precisión, puedes valerte de la función [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html) para convertir a una cadena dónde controlas la precisión con el formato, si quisieras contar los registros por minuto, por ejemplo, podrías hacer:

  ```
    SELECT   count(*)
           , to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') ts
           , org_account
           , result
           , mt_msc_addr
      FROM sms_data_mtbill
     WHERE time_stamp >= TO_DATE ('28-11-2018 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
       and mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), org_account, result, mt_msc_addr
     ORDER BY to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') DESC
  ```

  Si quisieras agrupar por hora, cambias el formato a `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'` y listo.

  Observa que he *formateado* la fecha en orden año-mes-día, para que mantengas la habilidad de ordenar por fecha. Obviamente esto no es amigable con el usuario y tendrías que *interpretar* esa fecha en la capa de presentación para mostrarla al usuario de forma amigable.
- Otra cosa que puedes hacer es convertir a texto y de regreso a un campo tipo fecha, para que el ordenamiento y presentación resulten más naturales, pero recuerda que esta doble conversión tiene un costo, por ejemplo:

  ```
    to_date(to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') ts
  ```
- Finalmente también puedes valerte de la función [`extract()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html), con los segmentos de tu interés (obviamente aquí se pierde totalmente el formato de fecha), pero la consulta tendría un mejor desempeño, por ejemplo::

  ```
    SELECT   count(*)
           , extract(day from time_stamp) dia
           , extract(month from time_stamp) mes
           , extract(year from time_stamp) anio
           , extract(hour from time_stamp) hora
           , extract(minute from time_stamp) minuto
           , org_account
           , result
           , mt_msc_addr
      FROM sms_data_mtbill
     WHERE time_stamp >= TO_DATE ('28-11-2018 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
       and mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY 
             extract(day from time_stamp) 
           , extract(month from time_stamp) 
           , extract(year from time_stamp) 
           , extract(hour from time_stamp) 
           , extract(minute from time_stamp) 
           , org_account
           , result
           , mt_msc_addr
     ORDER BY 
             extract(year from time_stamp) desc
           , extract(month from time_stamp) desc
           , extract(day from time_stamp) desc
           , extract(hour from time_stamp) desc
           , extract(minute from time_stamp) desc
  ```